# ServiceBusTrigger in Azure functions CLI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I tried to create a ServiceBusTrigger function, like in .NET Framework:

```
C:\Users\foo\test2>func new --language C# --template ServiceBusTrigger --name MyServicebusTrigger
Select a language: C#
Select a template: ServiceBusTrigger
Can't find template "ServiceBusTrigger" in "C#"
```

I can't find any documentation for what templates are included. Isnt there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct name is `Service Bus Queue trigger`

```
func new --language C# --template "Service Bus Queue trigger" --name MyServicebusTrigger
```

You can see the list of templates if you run the previous command without specifying `template` parameter.

Comment: I don't have a Service Bus template installed, how do I get it?

Comment: Which cli version are you on?

Comment: The latest preview: 2.0.1-beta.22

Comment: Yes, v2 template selection is quite limited so far, see [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/305)

Comment: Available templates can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-templates/tree/dev/Functions.Templates/Templates